# Accepting a URL or a PK as a filter in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-filter, django-filters

I am in the process of upgrading Django Rest Framework to the current version. With the new filtering available, I've found that any foreign key fields take a very long time for the initial page to load if there are several of them (the example I'm using below is `event` is a FK on the `Ticket` model). That said, I am using `filter_class` and passing the FK in Meta fields list:

```
# my viewset
class TicketViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Ticket.objects.all()
    filter_class = api_filters.TicketFilterSet


#my filterset
class TicketFilterSet(FilterSet):
    event = django_filters.NumberFilter(name="event")

    class Meta:
        model = Ticket
        fields = ["event", ]
```

In this example, passing a URL such as this works:
http://website.com/api/tickets/?event=19919

This URL does not:
http://website.com/api/tickets/?event=http://website.com/api/events/19919/

I would like to be able to accept either one. Obviously `NumberFilter` only works with a number, not a URL-- how can I use a filter that will accept either format?

Answer (score 1):

You really should try to get rid of the second form in the front end code. Any support for that full url parameter is just a work-around for bad design, and bad design will hurt you again and again.

If that's not possible, overload your ViewSet's `get` or `dispatch` (don't have the code in front of me so can't tell which one will work best) method and use a regex to get the id from the url and put that back into `request.GET` - which is a bit tricky as it's read-only so you have to clone it, modify the clone and assign that back to the request.